# Associate device tokens with specific user when using Parse for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

We are using `Parse` for iOS `APNS`, and so far it is working great. However, we are at the point where we need to associate a device token with a specific user of our app.

To do this, we decided that we should save the device token to our server so that it would be associated with that user. However, there are issues with this:

- What if they have multiple devices that they are using our app on?
- What if they unregister one of the devices?

Rather than using our server to handle the above situations, is there a way to let the `Parse` API tag device tokens with a username, so that we can pull all device tokens for that username and always send `APNS` to the most updated list of device tokens for that user?

Here is what I was thinking of doing:

```
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:self.deviceTokenData];
[currentInstallation setObject:@YES forKey:user.userID];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

So I would save the device token with an associated user ID from our app.

Or, is there another way that the `Parse API` can handle this situation?

**EDIT:**

Adding to the answer below, we would use something like the following on the server side to send to that user:

```
$user_id = // the user ID
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("user_id", $user_id);

ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => array(
    "alert" => "Welcome to the our awesome app!",
    "badge" => 1
  )
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have add a `userId` property to the installation object.

```
[currentInstallation setObject:user.userID forKey:@"userId"];
```

Then you can get a query of installations and send a push notification to that query:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:user.userId];
// Send push using this query
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I am wanting to do! On the other side of things, how could we do that query on the server side? Would we just use the REST API, or does the PHP API include queries like this?

Comment: I only have experience with the iOS and Javascript frameworks, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help!